# Formating programmatically Excel cells from Scientific numeric to Text with C#

Tags: c#, excel, format, numeric, excel-interop

I'm facing a problem after extracting data from my sqlServer dataBase to my Excel worksheet using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference. Numeric data are displayed in a scientific numeric format, instead of being displayed in a text format. I tried to format my cell this way, but still doesn't work : 
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell= (Range)  worksheet.Cells[rowNum, fieldNum];
cell.NumberFormat="@";`

I tried even to set my cells format in my Input Excel file; which i'm actually using as a template for this program; as Number or Text but helplessly it's not working.

How can i fix please this problem ?

Comment: Check Value and Value2 for the cell. I mean once you set value in the cell, log cell.Value.ToString() and cell.Value2.ToString(), see if the value is numeric or text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by using EntireColumn

```
cell.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";
```